# CSS class canceled text-align property

Tags: html, css, text-align

I changed CSS Class so my other list doesn't run the same code by CSS but the text-align code in the first code didn't run and I don't know why
I tried to put p tag and align right but it doesn't work, I also tried to put align attribute in "a" tag and it doesn't run too. I tried to put text-align attribute in CSS and it also doesn't run. But, only the text-align property which doesn't work. The rest of the CSS is fully working.

here's my CSS code:

```
.navbar-text ul{
flex: 1;
text-align: right;
}

.navbar-text ul li{
display: inline-block;
list-style: none;
margin: 0 25px;
}

.navbar-text ul li a{
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
padding: 0 10px;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
}
```

And here's my HTML code:

```
        <div class="navbar-text">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

And this:

```
        <ul>
            <li><a href="https://instagram.com/"><img src="instagram.png" alt=""></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/"><img src="twitter.png" alt=""></a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: You need to `text-align` the `li` or the `a` element.
Add. Sorry, what do you need to achieve? Could you be more specific?

Comment: Please be more specific on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: So, I use class so my second list doesn't get aligned to the right and to disabled the animation I put to the first list, but it somehow failed to align the first list

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put the second code